# How to access subgroup in list with Python

Tags: python, list, group

I have a list with subgroups within. I made subgrouping based on similarity of fund name. How do I select/identify a group within a list?

```
mylist = [
    {'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc A', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-5E', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-1', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-6', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-5', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-3', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-4', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-2'}
    {'MFS Conservative Allocation R3', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R2', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R6', 'MFS Conservative Allocation I', 'MFS Conservative Allocation A', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R4'}, 
    {'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-A', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-3', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-2', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-1'}]
```

For example how to I call/select 2nd group: `{'MFS Conservative Allocation R3', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R2', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R6', 'MFS Conservative Allocation I', 'MFS Conservative Allocation A', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R4'}`

My eventual goal is to keep only one fund from each group that is the best share class, but first I need a way to identify each subgroup.

Thanks

Comment: Use indexes: You can get the second element doing `myList[1]`

Comment: [Sequence Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

Comment: Those subgroups are sets, BTW.

Comment: You're missing the ending `]`.

Comment: You access the second subgroup the same way you access the second element of any other list. The type of the list elements has no effect on the way you access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice or indice the list index:

```
mylist = [{'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc A', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-5E', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-1', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-6', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-5', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-3', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc R-4', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc F-2'}, {'MFS Conservative Allocation R3', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R2', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R6', 'MFS Conservative Allocation I', 'MFS Conservative Allocation A', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R4'}, {'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-A', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-3', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-2', 'American Funds Cnsrv Gr & Inc 529-F-1'}]

MFSC = mylist[1]
print(MFSC)
```

Output:

```
{'MFS Conservative Allocation R2', 'MFS Conservative Allocation I', 'MFS Conservative Allocation A', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R3', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R4', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R6'}
```

But the element of list is a set so set element can appear in a different order every time you use them, and cannot be referred to by index or key.

```
MFSC = list(mylist[1])
print(MFSC)
```

Output:

```
['MFS Conservative Allocation R4', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R6', 'MFS Conservative Allocation I', 'MFS Conservative Allocation A', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R3', 'MFS Conservative Allocation R2']
```